# What is the default behaviour when list of tuples is sorted?

Tags: c#, list, tuples, .net-4.5

I want to sort a `List` of `Tuple<int, string>` using the `int` value. In this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-tuple) the following code is used:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "cat"));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(100, "apple"));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "zebra"));

list.Sort((a, b) => a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1));

foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

I noticed that if I changed the following line:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1));
```

to:

```
list.Sort();
```

the elements are again sorted.

Does this mean that the default behaviour is to use the first item? If yes, is there any performance difference between the two techniques?

Comment: [_"`List<T>.Sort()` Sorts the elements in the entire list using the default comparer of the object type held in the list"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: [Tuple<T1, T2>.IComparable.CompareTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd990083(v=vs.110).aspx) -> Example says that .Sort() is _sorted by its first component._

Comment: @DJmRek it says that it sorts by *all* components; the example in the code is a bad one, as there are no duplicates on the first component

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tuples compare themselves by comparing **each component in turn** using the default sort for that component. It isn't very clear, but ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990083(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> The `Tuple<T1, T2>.IComparable.CompareTo` method uses the default object comparer to compare each component.

This is slightly different to your example, as the sort will continue to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc component of the tuple (the `string` in your case) in the case of matches (2 items with `int` of `7`, for example)

Comment: why first it says, _to compare each component._ then the example says _array has been sorted by its first component_ ?

Comment: @Selman22 because there are no duplicates; try it for `{1, "c"}, {2, "a"}, {2,"c"}, {1, "a"}` to see it sort by both (the output should be `{1,"a"},{1,"c"},{2,"a"},{2,"c"}`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very interesting. I have just tested this and if I use only `sort()` the second items are compared if the first items are equal. But if I use the code from the link this is not the case.